# Where should I write and call GPIO port connection in the hardware interface in ros2_control for control of robot movement on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: control, raspberry-pi, differential-drive, ros-humble, hardware

I am using ROS 2 Humble on Raspberry Pi 4(Ubuntu 22.04 OS).

I am trying to build 2-wheeled diff-drive mobile robot and using `ros2_control` for controlling, but I'm not getting where should I write GPIO port connections part.

I am trying to control movement through Raspberry Pi GPIO pins using `ros2_control`. I have found many examples but with Raspberry Pi and Arduino serial connection not with only Raspberry Pi GPIO pins and L298N motor driver.

I'm not asking for code but where should it be written and whether it can be velocity controlled or not.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Shah, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: @Tully I have edited the question now. New to the forum so sorry for my mistakes. I just need to know where it should be written and if anyone can guide me little bit I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a GPIO interface can be specified in the <myrobot>.ros2_control.xacro file, as seen here: https://github.com/ros-controls/roscon2022_workshop/blob/1-robot-description/solution/controlko_description/urdf/rrbot/rrbot_macro.ros2_control.xacro.
Since this is just an xacro file, this is only providing the description of the interface to ros2_control, but keep following the example found in this repository to see how the hardware interface extends to the GPIO.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/ros-mobile-robots/diffbot

This code has the help you need. The Raspi can directly drive the Grove motor controller. It works very well.